# sql trigger unable to set variable from select

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know its asked question ,however I have tried few amendments but to no solution .
My trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE bookid INT;
DECLARE roomtype varchar(20);
DECLARE amount INT;
DECLARE m_count INT;
DECLARE curr_m varchar(20);
SET @bookid := NEW.id;
SET roomtype := (SELECT title FROM pm_booking_room WHERE id_booking=@bookid);
SET amount := (SELECT amount from pm_booking_payment WHERE id_booking=@bookid);
SET @curr_m:= (MONTHNAME(NOW()));
SET @m_count:= (SELECT count(*) FROM pm_report WHERE month=@curr_m);
INSERT INTO `pm_report`(`month`, `room_type`, `amount`) VALUES(@curr_m,@roomtype,@amount); 
END
```

whwn I check table, it inserts, but only @curr which is month name. Rest it inserts NULL
I tried
`SET @roomtype SELECT title FROM pm_booking_room WHERE id_booking=@bookid` but still same,NULL .
Also tried `SET @roomtype := (SELECT title FROM pm_booking_room WHERE id_booking=@bookid);` but still NULL.
I am using PhpMyadmin to create :

[image]
Please help.

Comment: Is this a before or after trigger?

Comment: you can refer to screenshot , however its after insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that `roomtype` and `@roomtype` are two different variables.

The variables you declare with the [local variable DECLARE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) have a scope within the body of one stored routine. They are never spelled with a `@` sigil.

The [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) with the `@` sigil have a scope of a MySQL session. You don't need to declare these kinds of variables. Just setting the variable to a value implicitly creates the variable.

You cannot `SET roomtype = ...` and expect that string to be read from the `@roomtype` variable. Nor vice-versa.

You appear to declare local variables, so you should use them consistently. But in some cases, your variable names are the same as column names, which will result in ambiguity if you use the variables in SQL statements that also reference tables with those columns. So you should adopt a naming convention to keep them distinct.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_bookid INT;
DECLARE v_roomtype varchar(20);
DECLARE v_amount INT;
DECLARE v_count INT;
DECLARE v_month varchar(20);
SET v_bookid := NEW.id;
SET v_roomtype := (SELECT title FROM pm_booking_room WHERE id_booking=v_bookid);
SET v_amount := (SELECT amount from pm_booking_payment WHERE id_booking=v_bookid);
SET v_month:= (MONTHNAME(NOW()));
SET v_count:= (SELECT count(*) FROM pm_report WHERE month=v_month);
INSERT INTO `pm_report`(`month`, `room_type`, `amount`) VALUES(v_month,v_roomtype,v_amount); 
END
```

(This code is not tested, so apologies if there are any mistakes. It is meant only to demonstrate using non-sigil variables consistently.)

Comment: thanks for pointing, tried with your code but still same

Comment: @retried, was creating trigger on different table. Hence sorted, however now I want to update and add `v_amount` to existing `amount` column `UPDATE pm_report set amount=amount+v_amount WHERE month=MONTHNAME(NOW()) and room_type=v_roomtype;` it saves NULL in amount

Comment: Is the `amount` column NULL to begin with?

Comment: No, it has value

Comment: Okay I don't have enough information to suggest an answer. I'll leave it to you to debug it.

Comment: ok, thanks for guidance. Can you just check if variable used in update query is right?
`UPDATE pm_report set amount=amount+v_amount WHERE month=MONTHNAME(NOW()) and room_type=v_roomtype;`

Comment: That looks right, assuming the table doesn't also have a column named `v_amount` or `v_roomtype`. The variable names need to be distinct from _any_ column in that table.